# Software to create hotel menus

Tags: gratis, open-source, windows-7, desktop-publishing

I need help in creating hotel menus. I want to create a hotel menu (which is going to be displayed on 65" LED screen).

I know that it is doable using Microsoft Publisher but I am looking for specific software (open source) and some basic guidelines if anyone knows about?

Comment: Could you include more detailed requirements? Basically, a simple ASCII text could be displayed on that screen. What features would you need? A database behind it to pick items from? A gallery for pictures? Graphic design stuff? Templates? What would make your wanted software "specific"?

Comment: This Question needs more specifics. For staff or customers? Is fancy layout and page design crucial? How often does the content change?

Comment: Well, I guess 65" LED for customers. And I can deal with internal stuffs (either design or layout). All what I needed was a software to do either. That's the forum meant for. isn't it? @BasilBourque.

Comment: @tbp_09 Stack Exchange is *not* a forum. Not intended for meandering open-ended discussions. The key to a Stack Exchange is narrowly defined questions on a specific topic, focused like a laser on a particular issue. You can read about the creators’ intentions [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/16.html) and [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). (StackOverflow was their first edition of a Stack Exchange.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly more generic that you would like but I would recommend taking a look at using [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) - Specifically the [Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) presentation tool.

- Free both Gratis & Open Source
- Cross platform - available for Windows, OS-X & Linux
- Lots of templates or you could prepare and keep your own
- Integrates with the Base database so you could build up a database of items with descriptions and use a selector to get this weeks menu, *(possibly with a separate output of the list of ingredients that you need to hand).*
- You can either have a static display, (which could also be done with Writer) or a Dynamic display that changes with time, with various transitions.
- Lots of export options including HTML for web content so you could use the one menu for both the LCD display and your website.
- You could even consider using a RasberryPi to do your display on the LCD.
- You can add custom dictionaries so as to ensure that dish names are correctly spelt, (including correct accents).

Comment: Thanks @steve. It seems to be useful and making sense to what I am trying to do.

Comment: Indeed, what I was looking for.